# Can't find bundle for base name messages

Tags: java, localization, resources, classpath, resourcebundle

I have the following structure of my bundle

[image]

But code

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resources/locales/messages", new Locale("ru"));
```

throws an exception

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resources/locales/messages, locale ru
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1499)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1322)
    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:795)
```

How can I load bundle from resources?

Comment: try `resources.locales.messages` instead of `resources/locales/messages`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name resources.locales.messages